# How to calculate total sum of absents of employee in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to count total number of absents of an employee.

when the calculated ratio is 0.00, it means that person was absent that day.
I want summary of total number of absents of an employee.

how can I count where Calculated Ratio is 0.00

**[Screenshot of Salary Report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeNvO.jpg)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use running total or use the condition like

```
If ratio=0.00
Then 1
Else 0
```

Now take the sum of that formula

Edit

```
If {TblTwistingSalarySheet.CalculationRatio} = 0 
Then 1
Else 0
```

Now take the count of this formula

Comment: I'm trying to use this but it's not working, 
If {TblTwistingSalarySheet.CalculationRatio} = 0
Then Count{TblTwistingSalarySheet.CalculationRatio}

it says the remaining text is not part of the formula

Comment: Post your full formula

Comment: that's my full formula, I just need to count number of times calculated ratio equals 0.

Comment: You didnt use open and closing braces for the count...enclose the database fields in braces for count function